# TLS between two iOS devices

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, secure-transport

I am currently developing an application which allows two establish a TLS session between two iOS devices.
The session is established between a Centra and a Peripheral that communicate via BLE (Core Bluetooth) library.
The server must hold the certificate and send it to the client which will validate it.
Does Apple's Secure Transport library handle all this automatically ? Is there any example for establishing a TLS session between two iOS devices ?

Thanks.